# Read randomly sentences from nltk corpus

Tags: python, nltk

I'm working on my university project and I have to read randomly 50 sentences from a NLTK Corpus (SemCor).

Currently I was only able to read the first 50 sentences as following:

```
from nltk.corpus import semcor as corpus

def get_sentence_from_semcor(sentence_num):
   sentence = " ".join(corpus.sents()[sentence_num])
   tags = corpus.tagged_sents(tag="sem")[sentence_num]
   for curr_word in range(len(tags)):
         if isinstance(tags[curr_word], nltk.Tree) and isinstance(tags[curr_word][0], str) and isinstance(tags[curr_word].label(), nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Lemma):
             word = tags[curr_word][0]
             target = tags[curr_word].label().synset()
             sentence_no_word = sentence.replace(word, "")
   return word, sentence_no_word, target

   corpus_sentences = [get_sentence_from_semcor(i) for i in range(50)]
```

Any Help on how I could select randomly 50 sentences of the corpus?

Comment: Investigate `random.sample` in random module. You provide `corpus_sentences` and the number of random.samples you want returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are wanting randomness, so let's import the `random` library:

`import random`

Then we need to know what our constraints are. Obviously, the earliest earliest1 we can select would be sentence 1, or sentence of index 0, but to know the max; we need to count the number of sentences, then subtract 1 to get the index of the last sentence.

`max_sentence = len(corpus.sents())-1`

We'll create an empty list to store our [pseudo]random numbers in:

`list_of_random_indexes = []`

then get some numbers in it (50 of them in this case):

```
for i in range(50):
    list_of_random_indexes.append(random.randint(0, max_sentence))
```

Then finish off with a modified version of your last line which now references our list of random numbers instead of the range:

`corpus_sentences = [get_sentence_from_semcor(i) for i in list_of_random_indexes]`

So all together:

```
import random
max_sentence = len(corpus.sents())-1
list_of_random_indexes = []
for i in range(50):
    list_of_random_indexes.append(random.randint(0, max_sentence))
corpus_sentences = [get_sentence_from_semcor(i) for i in list_of_random_indexes]
```

Or to make that a bit cleaner:

```
import random
max_sentence = len(corpus.sents())-1
list_of_random_indexes = [random.randint(0, max_sentence) for I in range(50)]
corpus_sentences = [get_sentence_from_semcor(i) for i in list_of_random_indexes]
```

But since you might want to not have duplicate lines, I would also do a check before appending the index that it isn't already in the list.

```
import random
max_sentence = len(corpus.sents())-1
list_of_random_indexes = []
while len(list_of_random_indexes)<50:
    test_index = random.randint(0, max_sentence)
    if test_index not in list_of_random_indexes:
        list_of_random_indexes.append(test_index)
corpus_sentences = [get_sentence_from_semcor(i) for i in list_of_random_indexes]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import numpy
length = len(nltk.corpus.semcor.sents())-50
for i in range(n_times):
   start = np.random.randint(0, length)
   corpus_sentences = [get_sentence_from_semcor(i) for i in range(start,(start+50))]
```

The code will iterate n_times returning a set of 50 sentences each time. 'start' is a random integer in the range(0, length). (assuming that you know the total length of the corpus).